# How to Migrate SharePoint server 2013 to SharePoint server 2016?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration, 2016

Please any link for this how to  Migrating SharePoint server 2013 to SharePoint  server 2016.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no official instruction how to migrate as SharePoint 2016 is yet to be released to the public yet.

Comment: Hi , SharePoint 2016 is released or not yet release.Anyone know releasing date of SharePoint 2016  please share with me.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Server 2016 will generally available on May 4th 2016( xcross fingers), you can join  [Microsoft is hosting a live,](https://vts.inxpo.com/scripts/Server.nxp?LASCmd=AI:4;F:QS!10100&ShowKey=30784&Referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fericoverfield.com%2Fsharepoint-2016-rtm-announced-general-release-early-may-2016%2F)

Right now, Trail version is available and you can download it from Microsoft site.

As far as Migration, In your case Database Upgrade approach is best. Same approach we did from 2010 to 2013 farm.

Also check: http://www.avepoint.com/community/avepoint-blog/choosing-upgrade-path-sharepoint-2016/